# How to retrieve a variable value from inside a do while loop

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and am working on a Mastermind project for a course.

I have a problem. I want to retrieve the value of `leftDigit` and put it into array `guess[4]`. But I don't know how to retrieve it outside the loop.

Let's say when I input the number 1234 and I want it to become `int[] guess = { 1, 2, 3, 4};`
`

```
public static void inputNumber(){   

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        currentRow++;

        System.out.printf ("Enter 4 numbers for attempt #%d: ", currentRow);

        int count = 10000, leftDigit;
        double tempNum;

        int number = input.nextInt();


        //finding the left digit   
        do{    
            tempNum = (double) number / count ;  
            leftDigit =  (int) (tempNum * 10) ;         
            count /=10;                         
            number = number - ( count * leftDigit);             
        } while (count != 1 );
    }
```

Comment: Not following you. What's your problem? leftDigit is available outside the scope of the loop, so you can just assign it normally. Or would you like to use `break` to get out of the loop at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which was posted works, but there are a few things that are unnecessary tho. Here's the code and I'll explain below:

```
int count = 1000;                    // notice I start at 1000, not 10_000
int[] guess = new int[4];
int i = 0;

do {
    guess[i++] = number / count;     // (1)
    number %= count;                 // (2)
    count /= 10;
} while (count != 1)
```

**(1):** because both number and count are typed *int*, the result will not be a floating point number and it won't be rounding up. it'll just truncate the floating part. For example: 8 / 3 == 2; 543 / 1000 == 0.

**(2):** This line will get the remainder of the division. For example: 16 % 5 = 1; 1043 % 1000 = 43. (Another way to write this line would be `number = number % count`).

Answer (score 1):

```
    int [] guess = new int[4];
    int i = 0;
    //finding the left digit   
    do{    
        tempNum = (double) number / count ;  
        leftDigit =  (int) (tempNum * 10) ;

        guess[i++] = leftDigit;

        count /=10;                         
        number = number - ( count * leftDigit);             
    } while (count != 1 );

    //Use guess as you want it contains the 4 digits you need
```

Comment: Given the `Homework` tag, it would be better if you explained a bit about what youre doing, what you changed, how it's different from the OP's solution.

Comment: Thank you, Nitin Chhajer ! Thank you very much !